# Why Java's JMF doesn't work in Linux?

Tags: java, linux, jmf

I have to do some image processing in Linux. I chose to use the JMF for my camera (a webcam). But my program is not able to access the camera, I get the error:  `javax.media.NoPlayerException: Cannot find a Player for :/dev/video0`. I tried the same program in Windows and it works fine.

The JMF is available for both Linux and Windows. And it may be installed in the OS itself or added in the project as the library. I tried both options. The driver for the camera is available in the OS, because the other software in the OS has the access to the camera. I tried it in my laptop and PC, but I am getting the same error.

Comment: What distribution of Linux are you running? Did you know that we on StackExchange have forums just for Linux? Try looking at askubuntu.com .

Comment: The linux I used was  Ubantu 10.04 LTS-the Lucid Lynx-released in April 2010 and supported until April 2013. And the link where I downloaded the JMF is from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142937.html